# Label when a New Class Starts

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have this table which records when a person took driving lessons and practiced at home. I have this scenario, whenever the `class_practice` column has **Simulation** for the value and `input_value` column has a **Yes** for it then Test_1 kicks off for that date. Subsequently, **Simulation** field is replaced with a **Class** value in the table. When that **Class** has a **Yes** then Test_2 kicks off and then another **Yes** means Test_3 and so on and so forth, Test_4, Test_5, etc....

How can I achieve this in postgreSQL 11.

```
select * from driving_table

student_name      class_practice     input_value       class_practice_date      
    Erin            Practice              Yes               2021-12-15      
    Erin            Practice              Yes               2021-12-16
    Erin           Simulation             No                2021-12-16
    Erin            Practice              Yes               2021-12-17
    Erin           Simulation             Yes               2021-12-17
    Erin            Practice              No                2021-12-18
    Erin             Class                No                2021-12-18
    Erin            Practice              No                2021-12-19
    Erin             Class                No                2021-12-19
    Erin            Practice              No                2021-12-20
    Erin             Class                Yes               2021-12-20
    Erin            Practice              No                2021-12-21
    Erin             Class                No                2021-12-21
    Erin            Practice              Yes               2021-12-21
    Erin             Class                No                2021-12-21
    Erin            Practice              No                2021-12-22
    Erin             Class                Yes               2021-12-22
    Erin            Practice              No                2021-12-23
    Erin             Class                No                2021-12-23
    Erin            Practice              No                2021-12-24
    Erin             Class                No                2021-12-24
    Danny           Practice              Yes               2021-12-15
    Danny           Practice              Yes               2021-12-16
    Danny          Simulation             No                2021-12-16
    Danny           Practice              Yes               2021-12-17
    Danny          Simulation             Yes               2021-12-17
    Danny           Practice              No                2021-12-18
    Danny            Class                Yes               2021-12-18
    Danny           Practice              No                2021-12-19 
    Danny            Class                No                2021-12-19
    Danny           Practice              No                2021-12-20
    Danny            Class                Yes               2021-12-20
    Danny           Practice              No                2021-12-21
    Danny            Class                No                2021-12-21
    Danny           Practice              Yes               2021-12-21
    Danny            Class                No                2021-12-21
    Danny           Practice              No                2021-12-22
    Danny            Class                Yes               2021-12-22
    Danny           Practice              No                2021-12-23
    Danny            Class                No                2021-12-23
    Danny           Practice              No                2021-12-24
    Danny            Class                No                2021-12-24
```

Requested Result:

```
student_name      class_practice     input_value       class_practice_date     test_simulation    
    Erin            Practice              Yes               2021-12-15               
    Erin            Practice              Yes               2021-12-16
    Erin           Simulation             No                2021-12-16
    Erin            Practice              Yes               2021-12-17            Test_1
    Erin           Simulation             Yes               2021-12-17            Test_1
    Erin            Practice              No                2021-12-18            Test_1
    Erin             Class                No                2021-12-18            Test_1
    Erin            Practice              No                2021-12-19            Test_1
    Erin             Class                No                2021-12-19            Test_1
    Erin            Practice              No                2021-12-20            Test_2         
    Erin             Class                Yes               2021-12-20            Test_2
    Erin            Practice              No                2021-12-21            Test_2
    Erin             Class                No                2021-12-21            Test_2
    Erin            Practice              Yes               2021-12-21            Test_2
    Erin             Class                No                2021-12-21            Test_2
    Erin            Practice              No                2021-12-22            Test_3
    Erin             Class                Yes               2021-12-22            Test_3 
    Erin            Practice              No                2021-12-23            Test_3
    Erin             Class                No                2021-12-23            Test_3
    Erin            Practice              No                2021-12-24            Test_3
    Erin             Class                No                2021-12-24            Test_3
    Danny           Practice              Yes               2021-12-15            
    Danny           Practice              Yes               2021-12-16            
    Danny          Simulation             No                2021-12-16
    Danny           Practice              Yes               2021-12-17            Test_1
    Danny          Simulation             Yes               2021-12-17            Test_1
    Danny           Practice              No                2021-12-18            Test_1
    Danny            Class                No                2021-12-18            Test_1
    Danny           Practice              No                2021-12-19            Test_1
    Danny            Class                No                2021-12-19            Test_1
    Danny           Practice              No                2021-12-20            Test_2
    Danny            Class                Yes               2021-12-20            Test_2
    Danny           Practice              No                2021-12-21            Test_2
    Danny            Class                No                2021-12-21            Test_2
    Danny           Practice              Yes               2021-12-21            Test_2
    Danny            Class                No                2021-12-21            Test_2
    Danny           Practice              No                2021-12-22            Test_3          
    Danny            Class                Yes               2021-12-22            Test_3          
    Danny           Practice              No                2021-12-23            Test_3          
    Danny            Class                No                2021-12-23            Test_3          
    Danny           Practice              No                2021-12-24            Test_3          
    Danny            Class                No                2021-12-24            Test_3
```

Comment: `'Test_' + nullif(count(*) filter (where class_practice = 'Simulation' and input_value = 'Yes') over (partition by student_name order by class_practice_date), 0)`

Comment: @shawnt00, `syntax error at or near "'Test_'"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select
    coalesce('Test_' || nullif(
        count(*)
          filter (where class_practice in ('Simulation', 'Class') and input_value = 'Yes')
          over (partition by student_name order by class_practice_date),
        0)::varchar(3), '')
from driving_table
```

Comment: This labels all the relevant records as `Test_1`. I covet to be able to encapsulate Test_2, Test_3 when the `Class` is `Yes`.

Comment: @Jake Try again.